# Convert String to JSON in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I have read data online, but it is in a string format. How can I make it so that it returns a JSON object.

Example data read:

```
text = '{"one":1,"two":2}'
```

Example conversion:

```
data = JSON.parse(text).to_json
```

But when I do:

```
puts data.class
#=> String
```

Comment: Hi Tushortz! Make sure to mark the correct answer!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Omit `to_json`: it will convert the hash back to json!  (JSON -> Hash -> JSON)

```
require 'json'
text = '{"one":1,"two":2}'
data = JSON.parse(text)  # <--- no `to_json`
# => {"one"=>1, "two"=>2}
data.class
# => Hash
```